# ¿Por que razón falla en la web pero no falla en forma local mi pagina?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5, codeigniter

tengo un sistema web que se encuentra en funcionamiento , pero cuando hago alguna modificación lo trabajo en forma local y una vez terminado la modificación recién subo los archivos , el problema es que de forma local no me presenta ningún problema pero en la web si sale diferente tipos de errores, trabajo con php framework codeigniter el error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
**500 (Internal Server Error) **

try{
w.send(l||b.data==null?null:b.data)
}catch(n){
c.handleError(b,w,null,n);c.handleComplete(b,w,e,f)}b.async||L();
return w}},param:function(a,b){var d=[],e=function(h,l){l=c.isFunction(l)?l():l;d[d.length]=
```

el codigo como les explique si funciona en forma local pero cuando esta en la web no funciona ..gracias

Comment: Estás usando algo para imprimir errores bonitos? Algo como whoops o kint? Ese código que aparece ahí parece un JS incompleto que no tiene que ver con el error de PHP

Comment: ese es el error que se produce y no me permite que siga lo siguiente que es guardar los datos, pero este error es del jquery dentro , es decir no he puesto ese codigo sino es del mismo query

Answer (score 1):

Estas subiendo los archivos por medio de un git o por medio de ftp?

En caso de que sea por FTP te recomiendo subir solo los archivos que fueron afectados ya que si subes todo de una vez vas a tener que editar el archivo config, db, y el .htaccess continuamente. A mi me pasó en mi primeros proyectos, otra cosa, si tu estas desarrollando en Windows y el servidor es UNIX recuerda que unix respeta las mayúsculas y minúsculas por lo que de acuerdo a las reglas en CI 3 el controlador debe nombrarse con una mayúscula al inicio.

El siguiente archivo .htaccess siempre me ha funcionado para cuando tengo problemas al redireccionar o cuando tengo un error 500 o 404:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

En caso de que no te funcione, prueba con este otro:

```
# index file can be index.php, home.php, default.php etc.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# condition with escaping special chars
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Espero te ayude, saludos!

Comment: donde pongo este codigo ?

Comment: En la carpeta raiz hay un archivo que se llama .htaccess